# Android : read a file from a specific character to another specific character

Tags: android, android-assets

I'm trying to read a txt file I have in assets. The structure of the file is like this: `1 [some text] 1 2 [some text] 2 3 [some text] 3 ...`.
What I'm trying to do is to read the `[some text]` part corresponding to a specific number, i.e. if i pass the number 1, I'll read from 1 to 1. I've tried this but it didn't work :

```
AssetManager manager = this.getAssets();
    InputStream input = null;
    InputStreamReader in = null;
    try {
        input = manager.open("facil/alexubago/songlyrics.txt");
        in = new InputStreamReader(input);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.d("ERROR DETECTED", "ERROR WHILE TRYING TO OPEN FILE");
    }
    try {
        char current;
        char current2;
        String themessage ="" ;
        while (in.ready()) {

            final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roland.ttf");
            final TextView extField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thelyrics);
            extField.setTypeface(tf);
            current = (char) in.read();
            int a = 1;
            char b = (char) a;
            if(current == b){
                    current2 = (char) in.read();
                while(current2 != b){
                    themessage = themessage+current2;}
                extField.setText(themessage);
                Log.d("caracter", ""+current);}
                Toast.makeText(lyricsfreakgame.this,themessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 1;
char b = (char) a;
```

This does not convert 1 to char '1'. Value of b is 1 not '1'. You should do like this

```
char b = '1';
```

Comment: The int a = 1 is just to test it the number given isnt given like that

Comment: Using int a=1, you are trying to read text within 1 block (1 [text] 1), right?